# How to handle retrive a data from two bundle in single form

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone if you would kindly help me. I'm stuck on how to retrieve the bundle data from another activity. Basically I have two activities which is that when I pressed a button on the first activity, it will go on the second activity and then sets the string values which is later on to be passed on the first activity. What I did was I used the bundle to put the string values. Here i have 3 forms. I am sending bundle values to second from from 1st form and returning bundle values from 3rd from to second from. 
 My question is that how can I handle the two bundle(activity) in 2nd form.

Comment: you get values from bundle using getIntent() method. it will retrieve the bundle for the activity which has produced your current activity. Best way to come over this issue would be Creating your own Global class which will save the data before you pass from one activity to another. and the other activity will just retrieve the data from Global class. you can keep data segmented according to your activities while you are using this will result in very clean code

Comment: No, not a global class .. global is bad on android ...

Comment: you can always nullify data from global as soon as you reach to next activity if it is carrying confidential data, as soon as you read the data just nullify that. in bundle if your activity can be launched from many other activities you will not be able to differentiate in getIntent() method which would be more cumbersome

Comment: I am updated source code here I am retriving values in onRestart()method but value is not displaying and this is second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first activity on button click you can do :

```
Intent in = new Intent(activtiy1, secondact.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("key", "string_to_pass");
.
.
.
in.putextras(b);
startActivity(in);
```

Now in Second activity you have to get bundle items :

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
String str =  b.getString("key");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Bundle doesn't have method `getStringExtra` ... also *In first activity on button click you can do :* is not a code ...

Comment: sorry, it was getString("key");

Comment: What do you really want??

Comment: Simon != Selvin ... did you notice ?

Comment: I noticed thats why i am asking what you want because in question it is not mention that there is edit button or any other button.

Comment: @Surender Kumer I think the talk goes around **you** using the **edit** button to fix your answer... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 you have first create ui for first activity like this

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".FirstActivity" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button 2" />

    </RelativeLayout>



    ui of second activity like this 




    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="second actvity" />

    </LinearLayout>



activity first code where i set index with intent for both button click(you also put string double ling and message with intent)


package com.example.teststart;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button b1,b2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id=v.getId();
        switch(id){
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent i1=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,secondactivity.class);
            i1.putExtra("one", 1);
            startActivity(i1);
        break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Intent i2=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,secondactivity.class);
            i2.putExtra("one", 2);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
        }
    }


}




and second activity i get that integer value to identify which button is clicked and fire operation on that condition


package com.example.teststart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class secondactivity extends Activity{
    TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondactvity);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
     int index = extras.getInt("one");
     if(index==1){
         tv.setText("nformation-A "+index);
     }else if(index==2){
         tv.setText("nformation-B "+index);
     }

}
}
```